# Webpack 5 Dev Server proxy seems to be ignored

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5

Firstly, this worked great in webpack 4. After upgrading to webpack 5, everything seems fine except the dev server proxy. Its like whatever values I put in there are just outright ignored.

All I get is the following error
*Error occured while trying to proxy: localhost:3006/api/configuration*

I also used to get logging out of the dev server but that seems to be being ignore too.
EG "Proxying from localhost:3006 to localhost:5050

Versions:

- webpack - 5.65.0
- webpack-dev-server - 4.7.2
- webpack-cli - 4.9.1

Webpack.dev.js

```
const path = require("path");
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin = require("@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin");
const ESLintPlugin = require("eslint-webpack-plugin");

const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

process.env.BABEL_ENV = 'development';
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: "development",
    devServer: {
        static: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
        historyApiFallback: true,
        port: 3006,
        proxy: {
            // '/api': 'https://localhost:5050',
            '/api': {
                target: 'https://localhost:5050',
                // pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' },
                secure: true,
            },
        },
        client: {
            logging: 'info',
            overlay: false,
        },
        hot: true,

    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./public/index.html",
            favicon: "./public/favicon.ico",
            title: "PBO Management | Dev | AWSM",
        }),
        new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin({
            overlay: false,
        }),        
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about webpack 4, but I think you need to use [`changeOrigin`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy) because you are using default ports in your server and webpack development server.

Also you might need to set `secure: false` if you don't have a valid SSL in your server.

```js
proxy: {
  '/api': {
    target: 'https://localhost:5050',
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true,
  },
},
```

Comment: I already have `changeOrigin: true`, and it's still not working.

Comment: @JohnManko You didn't have it in OP. I have tried your config with `changeOrigin: true` and `secure: false` and it worked for me! Are you still getting the same error?

Comment: @Amir Sorry for the slow response but this worked! I needed both `changeOrigin: true` and `secure: false`.  Thanks for your help.
My API was also missing the prefix EG localhost/config needed to be localhost/api/config. Hope that helps others too

Answer (score 1):

Same issue with webpack 5 (5.76.0)
When trying to proxying from localhost:3000 to localhost:8080

`changeOrigin: true` not working for me, I guess this is a bug.

I spended few hours and found only one worked solution
Using localhost for dev server and 127.0.0.1 for proxy

```
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api/': {
        target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/',
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: +1 for your solution. Also, it looks like there's an open issue for this. Maintainers want a minimum reproducible though; they don't yet recognize it as an issue I think. https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/4828

Answer (score 0):

For information:
I never got any of the suggested answers to work. But using router instead of target did the trick:

```
proxy: {
    '/api': {
        router: () => 'http://www.something-else.com/',
        logLevel: 'debug'
    }
}
```